Progressive matrix of line drawings
Not sure where my friend got it from, but here is it.


The answer is, I believe,

 the single dot. 



Here's my logic:

 On each line, the third shape is obtained by applying "AND" logic on horizontal/vertical lines of the two first shapes, and "XOR" logic on diagonal lines of the two first shapes. 




rot13(Guvf qrfpevcgvba npghnyyl nccyvrf gb gur pbyhzaf nf jryy nf gb gur ebjf.)
